# filter:Alpha(opacity=50) doesn't pass CSS validation

Tags: html, css, validation

The following CSS doesn't validate using http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Is it invalid?  Should it not be used, and if not, what should be used?

```
div.fade
{
   opacity:0.5;
   filter:Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: leave it, its fine probably gets flagged because its outdated but you need it for ie8

Comment: Actually, it will never validate because its browser specific. W3's validators validate based on the official standards. Things that other browsers add in will always be flagged.

Comment: It should not be used. If people are still using IE8 and older, then it's because they're deliberately going out of their way to make our lives difficult - after all, they must have manually disabled Windows Update otherwise they'd be on the latest versions!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, earlier versions of IE did not update automatically, nor were they flagged in Windows updates.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Some users may be using XP. In that case, the browser can't be upgraded beyond IE 8...

Comment: @David: W3C validators will ignore vendor prefixed properties, e.g. `-ms-filter`.  Unfortunately, `-ms-filter` doesn't work in older Internet Explorers anyway.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol.  Wow, tough position.  Maybe I should detect older browsers server-side, and return nothing to the bastards? :)

Comment: @user1032531 Haha, that might be a bit over the top xD But my position is mostly towards "making it look nice" (which is what opacity is usually for). 's why I don't use PIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter part, as you are using it, has never been part of the CSS spec and is proprietary to IE alone. That is why it's flagged as invalid.

Comment: Actually `filter` IS becoming standard, just not the way older IE did it. https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Comment: Thanks Rob,  So it will not validate, but I should keep it if I want older browsers to kind of work?

Comment: @user1032531 It will only work in IE (and old Opera? Don't recall). It will never work in any other browser.

Comment: @Rob  But it will not harm modern browsers?

Comment: @user1032531 No. Modern browsers are smart enough to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will select this answer in a couple of minutes.  You might want to update your answer stating that it could be used for older browsers without harming modern browsers.